# $or operator not recognized in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm taking an online course and I'm having an issue with a query. In the shell works fine, but when running the js file I get an error: unknown operator: $or. This is the revelant code:

```
var allOptions = [
    {
        overview: "wiki",
    },
    {
        milestones: "CMO"
    }
];
```

And then in a query function:

```
  var query = {};

    if ("overview" in options) {      
     query.overview = { "$or": [{"overview": {"$regex": options.overview, "$options": "i"}}, 
{"tag_list": {"$regex": options.overview, "$options": "i"}}] }
```

And in the shell, if I query like this:

```
db.companies.find({ $or: [{"overview": {"$regex": "wiki"}}, {"tag_list": {"$regex": "wiki"}}] }).count();
```

I get a result. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That needs to be `options[0].overview` since it's in an array. Alternately [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) to match the element from the array  Point is you are not referencing the correct element in the structure.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, changing to your suggestion `query.overview = { "$or": [{"overview": {"$regex": options[0].overview, "$options": "i"}}, {"tag_list": {"$regex": options[0].overview, "$options": "i"}}] }
        .overview`, I get the message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'overview' of undefined`

Comment: Added the answer by example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) the correct element:

```
var allOptions = [ { "overview" : "wiki" }, { "milestones" : "CMO" } ]

var query = { };
if ( allOptions.find( o => o.overview ) ) {

  var overview = allOptions.find(o => o.overview ).overview;
  // returns "wiki"

  query.$or = [
     {"overview": {"$regex": overview, "$options": "i"}}, 
       {"tag_list": {"$regex": overview, "$options": "i"}}
  ];
  // query is now like
  // { "$or": [{"overview": {"$regex": "wiki", "$options": "i" }}, {"tag_list": {"$regex": "wiki", "$options": "i" }}]
}

Company.find(query,function(err,results) {
  console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: @Mellville Show how you are passing `query` in your question. You are doing something else wrong as well as the construction. I've corrected the construction and also shown you how to correctly pass the argument.

Comment: now it works, thanks for the solution and explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the $or as the first query property, just like in the query you built for the shell.

For example:

`query.$or = [
    {"overview": {"$regex": overview, "$options": "i"}}, 
    {"tag_list": {"$regex": overview, "$options": "i"}}
]`

Comment: Nope. The code in the question does not correctly grab `options` as the value of `'wiki'` in the first place. That's what I've already corrected.

Comment: I recognised this question, so I've gone back to take a look, and the full context of the usage of the code is:
`var allOptions = [
    {
        overview: "wiki",
    },
    {
        milestones: "CMO"
    }
];

var numQueriesFinished = 0;
var companiesSeen = {};

for (var i=0; i<allOptions.length; i++) {
    var query = queryDocument(allOptions[i]);
    queryMongoDB(query, i);
}`

So in fact the issue was in the usage of
`query.overview`
instead of 
`query.$or`

Comment: Dude. It's already corrected. The previous process was incorrect, which is what is also corrected.

Comment: well it's not up to me to judge, but yes, Neil's Lunn answer is precise and complete wich can be handy to others. However, the downvote seems to harsh or not fair at all because both answers retrieved the same result - I tested. Of course, needs code adaptation, but still, it worked. So thank you both :)

Comment: Thanks @Mellville, Neil is right according to the information you gave. Appreciate the confirmation that my answer worked too :)